# Eclipse Warning message

Tags: java, eclipse

How to resolve warning message coming in eclipse editor when I am writing this below code

```
Map <String, Class> fieldTypes = new HashMap<String, Class>();
```

When I am adding Add @SuppressWarning 'rawtypes' to either above this line of above method, still eclipse showing this warning.

Thanks
Brajesh

Comment: What exactly is the warning? Would writing `Map <String, Class<?>> fieldTypes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>()` work?

Comment: Instead of `rawtypes` use `unchecked` SuppressWarning.

Comment: @Bragboy : I am getting this warning
Multiple markers at this line
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized

Comment: @ Harry Joy : Both not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
Map <String, Class<?>> fieldTypes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>(); //If you want all unknowns.
```

This requires no `SuppressWarnings`.

Answer (score 1):

Under `Window>Prefernces>Java>Compiler>Erro/Warnings` change the severity levels for `Annotations` sections

Comment: I don't want to change severity levels.

Answer (score 1):

In order to turn off the compiler warning for this specific message, set "Unchecked generic type operation" to 'Ignore'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right syntax?

The following works for me (on Eclipse 3.7.1) and suppresses the warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Map <String, Class> fieldTypes = new HashMap<String, Class>();
```

Comment: To remove warning he needs to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: no, he doesn't. Unchecked doesn't suppress a raw warning. You need to use "rawtypes". Test it out.

Comment: What you have written in your answer shows 2 warnings in my eclipse. 1. `Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` and 2. `Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized`.

Comment: looks like you are on an old version of eclipse. Eclipse 3.6 and above support rawtypes.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo).

Comment: time to upgrade, pal. The latest version is 3.7.1. You're way behind!

Comment: @dogbane : I am using Eclipse Indigo (3.7)

Comment: have you tried making Eclipse add the suppress annotation for you? Hover your mouse over the yellow warning line on top of the word "Class", then click on "Add @SuppressWarnings 'rawtypes' to 'fieldTypes'".

Answer (score 0):

If `fieldTypes` is not used you will get warning to avoid that you need to add

Add `@SsuppressWarnings` unused to main

Comment: In this case it will be better to remove it then adding an `unused` suppress warning.